# How do I style a HTML link without CSS?

Tags: html, css, blackberry

I need to style links for a Blackberry browser that has disabled CSS.

The following is what I try to achieve:

```
<style type="text/css">
a.hover { 
  border:0;
} 
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Is it even possible, just using html?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only set the color.

```
<body link="XXX" alink="YYY" vlink="ZZZ">
```

XXX being the color used for links, YYY the color when mouse hovers the link and ZZZ the color for already visited links. Color can be given in hex notation just like with stylesheets

```
#AABBCC
```

You cannot set whether links are underlined or not, or have a border or not. This is totally up to the browser... unless these devices have some special, secret non-standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`tex-decoration:bilnk`; this makes your text blink-blink, like rapper