# Can i change the text color of a tag without css?

Tags: html

I'm writing a template for an e-mail, and I can't use css. I need to change the color of the links, by default they get blue and underline. I want to keep the underline but change the color to black. Is that even possible without css?

My exact line is:

```
<tr><td><a href="#"> Link 3 </a></td></tr>
```

**EDIT**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299168/html-text-decoration-of-a-link-without-css) but it adds an attribute to the body section. That's also something I can't have. Any other solutions?

```
<body link="XXX" alink="YYY" vlink="ZZZ">
```

**EDIT**

[This link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is great if like me you have to write html for an email. I'm copying it here for posterity. Thanks @Andy.

Comment: Without using inline CSS or external files, no. Why can't you use CSS? There's a good reason the technology exists...

Comment: I don't know why but it's a requirement from the client. I can't use css, can't use divs, can't use javascript, can't use background images and a lot of other stuff. The worst is I'm not even a web developer :), I'm losing my hair here.

Comment: @BenM, thats incorrect, take a look at jangxx's answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "extra tags", instead of "external files". My error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you could do is use the old and deprecated font tag. So it would be:

```
<tr><td><a href="#"><font color="black"> Link 3 </font></a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, neither in the browser(im testing on chrome), visual studio or dreamweaver. The text color didn't change in any of them, neither inside or outside the <a> tag!

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko you are right. I guess I typed something wrong thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use below code:

```
<tr><td><a href="#" style="color:black;"> Link 3 </a></td></tr>
```

it is an inline CSS and as per your requirement you can use it into your email.

Comment: I think you should actually mention your solution *uses* CSS. It's inline CSS and should be fine to use in eMails.

Comment: This uses css, isn't it a problem in emails?

Comment: @JohannesWeiß No, this is not CSS, CSS stands for cascading style sheets. He is merely applying a style.

Comment: Try this code into your email and test as per your requirement

Comment: @pkachhhia I can't test it, I don't have access to their email. I'm just supposed to follow these guidelines. Sounds like a stupid question but for instance if I try it in my gmail I won't necessarily get the same result as in their email right?

Comment: @Andy thanks for the clarification. If that's correct it gives me liberty to apply those styles. Their exact words are "Do not use Cascading Style sheets, some e-mail environments do not support CSS".

Comment: @gameower This will be of help to you then: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ You can use any tags that are supported by all email enviornments. Or use them to progressively enhance a basic template

Comment: @Andy thanks a lot for that! Just to be sure if I got it right, that says where I can apply the style as pkachhia did in his reply?

Comment: Yes, it shows what email clients support what tags. So for example everything supports the `color` tag

Comment: Thank you for all the info! It really helped a lot. I'll stick with jagxx answer and try to avoid using styles as much as I can, just in case! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this in PURE HTML is to use *link* and *vlink* attributes.

```
<body link='black' vlink='black'>
        <a href='#'>Click Me</a>
</body>
```

Here, *link* is a unvisited hyperlink and *vlink* is a visited hyperlink.

To change color on hover use *alink* (active link) attribute of the body tag :

```
<body link='black' vlink='black' alink='green'>
    <a href='#'>Click Me</a>
</body>
```

In the above code the color of the link changes to green whenever you hover the link.

HOPE This Helped You!